# WordPress User profile page fields missing

Tags: wp-admin, users, profiles

My client has website up and running on wordpress and he is using wordpress 4.3. And i have noticed in Users--> user Profile section  field is missing in About yourself Section. I need these fields how can i get them back. Please guide me why is this issue?

There are two other fields and new section instead New Password and Repeat New Password which is Account Management section and contains New Password(Generate Password) and sessions field. I need New Password and Repeat New Password fields back.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is the new default password methodology used in WordPress 4.3.

In WordPress 4.3, if you have Javascript disabled or broken, then you will get the normal New Password and Repeat New Password fields. If you have Javascript enabled and running normally, then you only get the Generate Password button.

If you get two things on two different sites, then on one of them, you're not running Javascript for whatever reason. Could be something in your browser blocking Javascript code.

If you see the Generate Password button, and click it, then it will generate a strong password for you. You may choose to override that password and type in your own. If you use a weak password, then a checkbox will appear to confirm your decision to use a weak password. Either way, it won't stop you from using a weak password, and there will not be a Repeat Password field.

On the whole, the use of the Repeat Password field is actually less secure. The main reason for it existing was because passwords were typically hidden behind dots. You're typing blind. Therefore, the repeat field is to make sure you typed it the same way twice. However, this encourages passwords that are easy to remember and/or type. Actually showing the user the password as they type it makes them more confident that they typed it correctly, and eliminates the need for the second field. Additionally, adding in live confirmation about whether the password they have chosen is a good or bad one encourages them to pick good ones. The checkbox to confirm that they want to use a weak password encourages them to not use a weak password in the first place, and to make a stronger one.

This new password flow is designed to improve password security and reduce password related problems.

Answer (score -1):

<s>It sounds like you may have a plugin that is overriding the user-edit page, I would setup a dev environment mirroring the site and start disabling plugins until I knew which one was modifying the user-edit page. From there you may find it has a setting that allows you to turn it back on.</s>

The Profile section on a default WP install does not have a filter or action hook that allows you to remove it, so in all likelihood it is hidden with css or someone has modified the core files, if it's not a plugin.

See Otto's reply.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. How can i setup Dev environment mirroring of site so I can check that by disabling all plugins one-by-one and then inform you . Again thanks

Comment: You'll probably want to do some searching for tutorials and howtos based on your working environment, a good place to start is on the [developer.wordpress.org](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/setting-up-a-development-environment/) site. From there you will need to be sure to export the DB and import it into your dev environment.

Comment: Thank you so much again. I'll follow the article and implement this and update you. Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: One more thing can i deactivate plugins manually one by one on running website? I don't want to shutdown website for a minute.

Comment: You can do this on the live site, personally I wouldn't, but I believe many people do.

Comment: Not a plugin. This is the new standard default password mechanism in WordPress 4.3.